# Сколько ютуб-видео лучше добавить на страницу?

Tags: html, вёрстка, youtube

Допустим из админки будут добавляться `iframe` youtube на сайт, и количество добавляемых видео будет большое.
Сколько лучше должно быть видео на одной странице, чтобы страница быстро грузилась?  т.е. допустим чтобы сделать пагинацию.
И как добавить прелоадер с этой страницы `http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/06/youtube.html`, т.е. чтобы прелоадер грузился из админки?

Comment: Чтобы быстро грузилась - очевидно, ноль :) Если ноль не устраивает, эначит подбирайте приемлемое для вас значение опытным путём (секундомер никто не отменял)

Comment: >>Сколько лучше должно быть видео на одной странице, чтобы страница быстро грузилась?<< замеры показывают, что быстрее всего когда количество видео равно 0

Comment: А, меня опередили)

Comment: т.е. такого показателя нет, как количество видео на одной странице? как добавлять прелоадер в админке? можно ли это сделать программно?

Comment: @word Есть массив картинок от ютуба, куда вы в цикле подставляете идентификатор видео, если изображение существует, показываете его.

Comment: @DaemonHK, а программно это можно как-то сделать, т.е. создать массив картинок для ютуба? или нужно предварительно подготавливать картинки?

Comment: @word посмотрите мой ответ, вы это имели в виду?

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то как вариант:

```
<?php
$videoId = "JMJXvsCLu6s";
$ytImages = ["default","mqdefault","hqdefault","sddefault","maxresdefault"];
foreach($ytImages as $image){
  $headers = get_headers("https://img.youtube.com/vi/JMJXvsCLu6s/{$image}.jpg");
  if ($headers[0] == "HTTP/1.0 200 OK") {
    echo "<img src=\"//img.youtube.com/vi/{$videoId}/{$image}.jpg\">";
  }
  unset($image);
}
```